# Safari Javascript Console Autoscrolling

Tags: macos, safari, console

Is it possible to make the javascript console in Safari 6 automatically scroll down to show the most recent log? Currently, I have to manually scroll down every time I log something.

Comment: current answer is outdated (2022)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Safari 6 but in my Safari (v 7.0.5), there is a small select in the bottom right corner of the console that says "Main Frame" by default but by switching to "gooleViewer" option, Safari auto-scrolls to the latest entry. Hope that helps.

Comment: current answer is outdated (2022)